# Setting sort = False in groupby unstacking my multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use groupby without any sort.
However if I set `sort` to false, my multindex df unstacks.

`sort = True` (expected result, except for the sorting issue):

```
         level_0                                                  
Friday    3M           -0.002532            12             0.666667
          6M           -0.002532            12             0.666667
Monday    3M            0.126991            12             0.833333
          6M            0.126991            12             0.833333
Thursday  3M            0.047767            13             0.461538
          6M            0.047767            13             0.461538
Tuesday   3M           -0.077558            14             0.285714
          6M           -0.077558            14             0.285714
Wednesday 3M            0.002976            13             0.615385
          6M            0.002976            13             0.615385
```

`Sort = False:` (level_0 seems to have unstacked )

```
               total_returns  total_counts  positive_day_chance
          level_0                                                  
Monday    3M            0.126991            12             0.833333
Tuesday   3M           -0.077558            14             0.285714
Wednesday 3M            0.002976            13             0.615385
Thursday  3M            0.047767            13             0.461538
Friday    3M           -0.002532            12             0.666667
Monday    6M            0.126991            12             0.833333
Tuesday   6M           -0.077558            14             0.285714
Wednesday 6M            0.002976            13             0.615385
Thursday  6M            0.047767            13             0.461538
Friday    6M           -0.002532            12             0.666667
```

I want the behavior of sort = True, without the sorting.

Here is the code for the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__) # 1.0xx

'''

            level_0  total_returns  total_counts  positive_day_chance  
Monday         3M       0.126991            12             0.833333   
Tuesday        3M      -0.077558            14             0.285714   
Wednesday      3M       0.002976            13             0.615385   
Thursday       3M       0.047767            13             0.461538   
Friday         3M      -0.002532            12             0.666667
Monday         6M       0.126991            12             0.833333   
Tuesday        6M      -0.077558            14             0.285714   
Wednesday      6M       0.002976            13             0.615385   
Thursday       6M       0.047767            13             0.461538   
Friday         6M      -0.002532            12             0.666667




'''

df = pd.read_clipboard()

print('sort: False', '\n')
print(df.groupby([df.index, 'level_0'], sort = False).sum())
print('sort: True', '\n')
print(df.groupby([df.index, 'level_0']).sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking to sort by a custom (i.e. not lexicographic) order. Tthe best way to do it is to use Categoricals. In this case, make it a CategoricalIndex and specify the ordering, i.e. :

```
weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]
df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index, categories=weekdays)
```

I get the same result with this solution regardless of what sort is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is unclear what you want. In your dataframe you only have one row for each (day, level_0) key.

I changed your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
print(pd.__version__) # 1.0xx

s = '''
            level_0 total_counts  positive_day_chance
Monday        3M  1             0.8
Friday        3M  2             0.7
Monday        6M  3             0.6
Friday        6M  4             0.5
Monday        6M  5             0.4
Friday        3M  6             0.3
Friday        3M  7             0.2'''


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=r'\s+')

print('sort: False', '\n')
print(df.groupby([df.index, 'level_0'], sort = False).sum())
print('sort: True', '\n')
print(df.groupby([df.index, 'level_0']).sum())
```

---

```
0.24.2
sort: False 

                total_counts  positive_day_chance
       level_0                                   
Monday 3M                  1                  0.8
Friday 3M                 15                  1.2
Monday 6M                  8                  1.0
Friday 6M                  4                  0.5
sort: True 

                total_counts  positive_day_chance
       level_0                                   
Friday 3M                 15                  1.2
       6M                  4                  0.5
Monday 3M                  1                  0.8
       6M                  8                  1.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

With `sort=False` the (day, level_0) group keys are not sorted whereas with `sort=True` you can see all the `Friday` rows then the `Monday` rows.

Plus in my example you can see that the values of the columns are added.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Basically I am confused as to why I am not getting the `unstacked` look with unsorted.  It makes it easier to parse the dataframes I have. 
I can't use sort, as current order is important.